# Using dataLayer without numbers

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

Is there any way to write a dataLayer check (using Google Tag Manager) without using numbers?

Currently, I am using:
gtm.element.51.value

Here is a screenshot of the dataLayer structure. Condensed for viewing.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwNjx.jpg]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwNjx.jpg

I have checkboxes that dynamically appear on this page, thus making the "51" number change depending on the number of checkboxes they select.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you are trying to do with your code. You shouldn't rely on GTM's naming convention as this can change at any time, especially as new triggers and variables are added to the container.

Comment: Thanks for the reply vinoaj. It's a little confusing to explain but in a general sense, I am trying to capture the zip code field when the form is submitted. Thats why I was hoping to somehow target the "select#p_lt_...." name. Because 51 is not always the number depending on how many checkboxes appear.

Comment: Can the field be identified by a unique id or CSS selector? You might be better off using GTM to access the values that way and pass it to your tags.

Comment: That is a great idea. I didn't even consider just doing a custom javascript variable to pull that data. Thanks for bringing that to my attention!